# I don't understand what is wrong with my code (pointers and template)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void getMinMax(T tab[], int nbPers, float *min, float *max){
    *min = FLT_MAX; 
    *max = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nbPers; i++){
        if (tab[i] < *min){
            *min = tab[i];
        } 
        if (tab[i] > *max){
            *max = tab[i];
        }
    }
    printf("min : %.2f , max : %.2f", *min, *max);
}


int main()
{  
int     age[]    = { 27, 35, 41, 18, 25, 30, 54, 50 };
float taille[]  = { 1.72 , 1.65, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.54, 1.83, 1.71 },
        poids[] = { 65.3, 67.1, 74.8, 60.7, 72.3, 56.4, 66.9, 72.1};
int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);
float *min; 
float *max;

printf ("3. valeurs min et max avec pointeurs\n");
getMinMax(age, nbPers, &min, &max);

return 0;
}
```

My goal is to get the min and max value from the 3 arrays so 6 values in total, using pointers. When I try to compile I get this error :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'getMinMax(int [8], int&, float**, float**)
```

and these notes :

```
note: candidate: 'template<class T> void getMinMax(T*, int, float*, float*)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   cannot convert '& min' (type 'float**') to type 'float*'
```

I can't find what these mean, I believe that my template causes problems

Comment: *error: no matching function for call to '`getMinMax(int [8], int&, float**, float**)`'* Means that you are calling `getMinMax` with the argument types the error is showing, but you haven't declared the function anywhere with those argument types. Note that, specifically `&min` and `&max` are of type `float **` not `float *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful tip when debugging template stuff: get rid of the template!  In this case, rewrite getMinMax as a plain old function.  If it works, then you know the problem was something specific to templates.  If it doesn't, then you made a mistake unrelated to templates.  In fact, unless the template you're writing is very simple and/or you're very experienced with this stuff, you should write it as a plain function first, and only convert to a template when it already works.

The standard "trick" to make this easy is to use a typedef.  That is, instead of starting with `template<class T>` and then rest of the function, simply start with something like `typedef float T;` and then the rest of the function.  Then the compiler will treat T as just another name for "float".  Or you can use a more specific name that T, such as `typedef float Number;` if you intend your function to be used on numbers.

I suggest you try this trick on getMinMax: comment out the template line and put in the ttpedef line instead.  Your code will still not compile, but the compiler error messages will usually be much easier to understand.

I see at least one mistake in your code already, but rather than point it out, I decided to share this technique which I think will enable you to find the problem pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void getMinMax(T tab[], int nbPers, float *min, float *max){
    *min = FLT_MAX; 
    *max = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nbPers; i++){
        if (tab[i] < *min){
            *min = tab[i];
        } 
        if (tab[i] > *max){
            *max = tab[i];
        }
    }
    printf("min : %.2f , max : %.2f", *min, *max);
}


int main()
{  
int     age[]    = { 27, 35, 41, 18, 25, 30, 54, 50 };
float taille[]  = { 1.72 , 1.65, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.54, 1.83, 1.71 },
        poids[] = { 65.3, 67.1, 74.8, 60.7, 72.3, 56.4, 66.9, 72.1};
int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);
float *min; //PROBLEM # 1
float *max; //PROBLEM # 1

printf ("3. valeurs min et max avec pointeurs\n");
getMinMax(age, nbPers, &min, &max); //PROBLEM # 2

return 0;
}
```

**Problem # 1:** You are using uninitialized `float` pointers `min` and `max`. You need to initialize them like so, then `delete` (so as to not have a memory leak) them:

```
int main()
{
    int     age[] = { 27, 35, 41, 18, 25, 30, 54, 50 };
    float taille[] = { 1.72 , 1.65, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.54, 1.83, 1.71 },
        poids[] = { 65.3, 67.1, 74.8, 60.7, 72.3, 56.4, 66.9, 72.1 };
    int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);
    float* min = new float; //initialized!
    float* max = new float; //initialized!

    printf("3. valeurs min et max avec pointeurs\n");
    getMinMax(age, nbPers, &min, &max); //still a problem here
 
    delete min; //no memory leak!
    delete max; //no memory leak!

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem # 2:** `min` and `max` are already `float*`. Using `&` on them will give a `float**`. To fix this, merely do this:

```
int main()
{
    int     age[] = { 27, 35, 41, 18, 25, 30, 54, 50 };
    float taille[] = { 1.72 , 1.65, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.54, 1.83, 1.71 },
        poids[] = { 65.3, 67.1, 74.8, 60.7, 72.3, 56.4, 66.9, 72.1 };
    int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);
    float* min = new float;
    float* max = new float;

    printf("3. valeurs min et max avec pointeurs\n");
    getMinMax(age, nbPers, min, max); // note I am not using &

    delete min;
    delete max;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, to debug templates, it is often a good practice to remove the template, and replace all the generic types with a fixed type, eg `int`.

Transcription of errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'getMinMax(int [8], int&, float**, float**) //See Problem # 2.


note: candidate: 'template void getMinMax(T*, int, float*, float*) //getMinMax is a possible function to call, but because of the float**s instead of float*s, as said in Problem # 2, it is not called
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note: cannot convert '& min' (type 'float**') to type 'float*' //see Problem # 2
```

Comment: Actually it might be even better to just declare min and max as plain old floats, rather than float pointers, and then there's no need to introduce new and delete.